# Spring: Использование RequestPart вместо RequestBody

Tags: javascript, spring, angular

Не могу на сервере принять запрос из клиента с телом Json Object & MultipartFile. Выдает следующие ошибки:

`The request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found`:

```
formData.append('idea', JSON.stringify(idea));
formData.append('addImages', file);
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed'
}
```

`Required request part 'idea' is not present`:

```
formData.append('idea', JSON.stringify(idea));
formData.append('addImages', file);
headers: {
  'Content-Type': 'multipart/mixed;boundary=gc0p4Jq0M2Yt08jU534c0p'
}
```

`Content type 'application/octet-stream` not supported:

```
formData.append('idea', JSON.stringify(idea));
formData.append('addImages', file);
```

**Controller**

```
@PostMapping("/idea/save")
public ResponseEntity<Idea> saveIdea(@RequestPart("idea") @Valid Idea idea,
                                     @RequestPart(required = false) List<MultipartFile> addImages,
                                     @RequestPart(required = false) List<MultipartFile> addFiles,
                                     Principal principal) {

    return new ResponseEntity<>(ideaService.add(idea, addImages, addFiles, principal.getName()), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

Скорее всего нужно добавить спрингу какой-то конвертер и применить случай 1 или 2. Если это так, то дайте наводку на чертеж.

Answer (score 0):

Решил с помощью реализации AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter

### AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter

```
@Component
public class MultipartJackson2HttpMessageConverter extends AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter {

/**
 * Converter for support http request with header Content-Type: multipart/form-data
 */
public MultipartJackson2HttpMessageConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    super(objectMapper, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
}

@Override
public boolean canWrite(Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean canWrite(Type type, Class<?> clazz, MediaType mediaType) {
    return false;
}

@Override
protected boolean canWrite(MediaType mediaType) {
    return false;
}
}
```

### Controller

```
@PostMapping("/idea/save")
public ResponseEntity<Idea> saveIdea(@RequestPart("idea") @Valid Idea idea,
                                     @RequestPart(required = false) List<MultipartFile> addImages,
                                     @RequestPart(required = false) List<MultipartFile> addFiles,
                                     Principal principal) {

    return new ResponseEntity<>(ideaService.add(idea, addImages, addFiles, principal.getName()), HttpStatus.CREATED);
}
```

### Client

```
public put(idea: Idea, formData: FormData): Observable<Idea> {
  formData.append('addImages', this.addImages);
  formData.append('addImages', this.addFiles);
  formData.append('idea', JSON.stringify(idea));
  return this.httpClient.put<Idea>(`${this.apiBaseUrl}/idea/put`, formData);
}
```

Благодаря https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16230291/requestpart-with-mixed-multipart-request-spring-mvc-3-2/18503158